# findOneAndUpdate in mongoose (MERN)

Tags: mern

A small bottleneck arose while developing a short tutorial:
I would like to be able to push this model:

```
    const studentFatherSchema = new Schema ({
        yam:{
            type: String,
            trim: true
        },
        emailmanagement: {
            type: String,
            trim: true
        },
        students: [{
            name: {
                type: String,
                trim: true
            }
        }]
    });
```

Would I first have to find the parent object with `findById (req.params.studentFatherId)` and then do the update, or can I do it all at once? I'm trying to do it all at once, but I can't, what do you recommend?
Note: I can update the name and `emailmanagement` fields without problems, but doing an update with the push does not add it to me, I am testing it with Postman and

I have something like this but it doesn't work!

```
    exports.updateAddChild = async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const student = req.body;
            const studentFather = await StudentFather.findOneAndUpdate (
                {_id: req.params.studentFatherId},
                {$ push: {students: student}},
            );
        } catch (error) {
            console.log (error);
            next ();
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: the request in JSON format in Postman is this:
{
     "students": [
         {"name": "student name", "nif": "55555555-t"},
         {"name": "student name added", "nif": "44444444-t"}
     ]
}

Comment: Now I have managed to run the function correctly, but I do not get the desired result, since it does not perform a push, but the data contained in the array is replaced by the inserted ones, that is, the data that existed before invoking is not preserved to function.